# How Visual deliver it's list of Drawing objects to rendering system?

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to figure out how WPF rendering system works and now I'm stuck
for several days with question:

How Visual deliver it's list of Drawing objects to rendering system ?

I don't see members of Visual that serve that purpose.

Simply put, what I have to implement in:

```
public class MyVisual : Visual
{
   // ???
}
```

so that

```
DrawingGroup dg = VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing( new MyVisual() );
```

become non-null (valid DrawingGroup object) ?

**Edit (March 14 2013):**

**I expected this question should be very easy to answer for anyone who
understand WPF, but as it seems, it's not.**

**I asked this question more than a week ago and this very specific, concrete,
and fundamental question about WPF architecture was left unanswered in spite
of presence of so many experts for WPF around. Is it posible that no one of
those WPF experts, who answers so many "upper level" questions, actually
don't know how WPF function at it's base level ?**

**Actually, my question in fact is: Is there any real expert for WPF or is it
so mysterious that is beyond human understanding ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for `DrawingGroup dg = VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing( new MyVisual() );` to work, you would need to override `Visual.GetDrawing`. However, this is an `internal virtual` method, so you can't override it.

I don't think deriving directly from `Visual` is a supported scenario; you should derive from `UIElement` or use (via composition or inheritance) one of the other `Visual`-derived classes, e.g., `DrawingVisual` (which exposes a public `RenderOpen` method).

Comment: No, you wouldn't need to override the method.  That's somewhat like saying "I have to override the `Title` property in order to get a caption of my choice."  You can set the variable it already returns.  For `Title`, you call its setter.  For the `Drawing` property, you call `RenderOpen()` and add at least one drawing.

Comment: @BenVoigt: The OP was asking about deriving from `Visual`, which I still maintain isn't a supported scenario. I already mentioned using `DrawingVisual.RenderOpen` in my answer; `Visual` doesn't have a `RenderOpen` method (so I'm not sure to what you're referring).

Comment: Sorry about the trivial edit, changing votes requires an edit to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

As Bradley mentions, you should be deriving from `DrawingVisual` instead of `Visual` to make this work.

---

You're doing it backwards.  The `Visual` is empty until you render something into it.  That something can be an empty `DrawingGroup`...

To get a `DrawingGroup` corresponding to the content of a `Visual`

```
DrawingGroup dg = new DrawingGroup();
using (DrawingContext myContext = myVisual.RenderOpen())
    myContext.DrawDrawing(dg);
```

Everything that happens between `RenderOpen` and disposing the `DrawingContext` goes into a `DrawingGroup`, which the `Visual` stores internally.

After that,

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing( myVisual )
```

will be a non-null `DrawingGroup` (I haven't checked whether it is the one created above, or a WPF-created `DrawingGroup` with one item inside, the one created above).

If you want `VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing( new MyVisual() )` to work, you just need to perform the above stuff inside `MyVisual`'s constructor:

```
MyVisual()
{
    using (DrawingContext myContext = RenderOpen())
        myContext.DrawDrawing(new DrawingGroup());
}
```

and there you go, the internal data structure used by `GetDrawing` is correctly set up.  No need to override it.

Comment: This code doesn't compile, because `Visual` (from which `MyVisual` is derived in the OP's question) doesn't have a `RenderOpen` method.

Answer (score 0):

[Answer to Phil: That would be nice except Visual does not have method OnRender. You are actually talking about UIElement.]

I would be satisfied if someone could just confirm that this line from MSDN is incorrect:

"The Visual object provides support for:
[among other things] 
- Output display: Rendering the persisted, serialized drawing content of a visual...".

As UIElement, ContainerVisual or Viewport3DVisual all have different mechanisms of Drawing content delivery, then this means that Visual itself does not have one central (polymorphic kind of) mechanism of Drawing delivery but those role fall onto these three predefined classes (in other words, you can not create new kind of Visual that does not derive from one of those three because rendering system will not be able to render it because it only know how to handle these three classes, but not Visual itself).

Am I right ?

Edit:

**NO. THIS CONCLUSIONS ARE INCORRECT BECAUSE THEY ARE BASED SOLELY ON WHAT IS PRESENTED IN MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION. THERE ARE MORE TO VISUAL OBJECT THAN WHAT IS IN DOCUMENTATION. TO DIG OUT MORE USE REFLECTION.**

Comment: In order for `DrawingGroup dg = VisualTreeHelper.GetDrawing( new MyVisual() );` to work, you would need to override `Visual.GetDrawing`. However, this is an `internal virtual` method, so you can't override it.

I don't think deriving directly from `Visual` is a supported scenario.

Comment: You just open my eyes, man! There is a whole new world down there. I just checked reflection data for Visual thoroughly and there it was. Thank you and please send your contribution as answer so I could give you a "good answer" point.